# How to select string inside field mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();

    try{
        Bson projection = fields(include("name"), exclude("_id"));
        col.find(query).projection(projection).forEach(doc ->
                System.out.println(doc.toJson()));
        cursor.close();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Essentially this is a query that finds all of the fields that include the name "name" for whatever is in my columns, my output for each name is usually

`{"name": "WhateverNameIs"}`

How can I only access the name inside the actual field itself, so I can compare that string name with something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this a few hours later, for anyone wanting the answer to this for the future then here it is:

```
JsonObject obj = new JsonParser().parse(document.toJson()).getAsJsonObject();
String name = obj.get("name").getAsString();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).